# Installing gcc-fortran on Suse Enterprise edition

Tags: linux, gcc, package-managers, suse

I'm trying to install R on my office server (running Suse Enterprise edition with no GUI ) and the wiki asks me to install some stuff before i install R

```
readline-devel
xorg-x11-devel
gcc-fortran
```

I managed to install the first 2 , getting the RPMs and the dependencies' RPMs but i'm really running into problems when installing the gcc-fortran package .

I was wondering if there is any package manager that i can use that would take care of the dependencies for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out .

The problem was that the gcc-fortran package and all the other dependencies were stored in a dvd somewhere on my office network . This wasn't given anywhere in the wiki!

So all i had to do was whip out yast2 , add the repo's and get installing !

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Suse, but it should have YUM as a package manager.

```
yum --help
```

or

```
man yum
```

should help you.

Answer (score 0):

A search [here](http://software.opensuse.org/search?q=gcc-fortran&baseproject=openSUSE:12.1&lang=en&exclude_debug=true) finds the package so you should be able to install using yum, as @Anonymous mentiond, or rpm.